# OrderBy Expression When Using An Association Table

Tags: entity-framework

I have two tables: `CommentCategories` and `Comments`. It is a many-to-many relationship. There is a `CommentCategory_Comment` association table. But that table contains a `orderOfCommentInCategory` field, so EF represents the association by creating a seperate entity rather than navigation properties.

I am trying to get the comments under a certain category and orer them by the `orderOfCommentInCategory` field. How should be the `OrderBy` expression that needs to be added to the query below?

```
List<Comment> comments = category.CommentCategory_Comment
                                 .Select(ccc=>ccc.Comment)
                                 .OrderBy(???)
                                 .ToList();
```

Comment: Move the OrderBy one line up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @GertArnold recommends the only you need to do is order first before select:

```
  var comments = category.CommentCategory_Comment
                         .OrderBy(c=>c.orderOfCommentInCategory )
                         .Select(ccc=>ccc.Comment)
                         .ToList();
```

Using query syntax:

```
var query= from cc in category.CommentCategory_Comment
           orderby cc.orderOfCommentInCategory
           select cc.Comment;

var comments=query.ToList();
```